# [C/C++][CGIcc] GET works but POST results in error message

Tags: c++, apache, cgi, fastcgi

I am new to CGI. I use Apache v2.2 and GNU cgicc v3.2.9. I want to use CGI for generating a HTML web page with a simple form. Aim of this work is to let an user send data by hiting a button on this CGI directly back to the "same" CGI. The CGI evaluates the data and changes the web page:

CGI --> CGI --> CGI --> ...

I can not use a simple HTML page and sending the requests to a cgi because after that I have created a CGI page were the user can send again a request to this cgi which leads to the same situatiuon as introduced:

HTML --> CGI --> CGI --> CGI --> ...

Using form method POST leads into a server error message while GET works:

access.log

> [16/Mar/2011:15:00:50] "GET
> /cgi-bin/cgiHandleEvents.cgi HTTP/1.1"
> 200 973
>
> [16/Mar/2011:15:00:52] "GET
> /cgi-bin/cgiHandleEvents.cgi?value1=&value2=option1&value3=button1&value4=data4
> HTTP/1.1" 200 973
>
> [16/Mar/2011:15:01:34] "GET
> /cgi-bin/cgiHandleEvents.cgi HTTP/1.1"
> 200 974
>
> [16/Mar/2011:15:01:37]
> "POST /cgi-bin/cgiHandleEvents.cgi
> HTTP/1.1" 500 538

error.log *(I reduced the http:// to http// because of spam warning regarding my stackoverflow reputation)*

> [Wed Mar 16 15:01:37 2011] [error]
> [client 127.0.0.1] Premature end of
> script headers: cgiHandleEvents.cgi,
> referer:
> http//localhost/cgi-bin/cgiHandleEvents.cgi
>
> [Wed Mar 16 15:01:37 2011] [error]
> [client 127.0.0.1] \r, referer:
> http//localhost/cgi-bin/cgiHandleEvents.cgi
>
> [Wed Mar 16 15:01:37 2011] [error]
> [client 127.0.0.1] This application
> has requested the Runtime to terminate
> it in an unusual way., referer:
> http//localhost/cgi-bin/cgiHandleEvents.cgi
>
> [Wed Mar 16 15:01:37 2011] [error]
> [client 127.0.0.1] Please contact the
> application's support team for more
> information.\r, referer:
> http//localhost/cgi-bin/cgiHandleEvents.cgi
>
> [Wed Mar 16 15:01:37 2011] [error]
> [client 127.0.0.1] terminate called
> after throwing an instance of
> 'std::runtime_error'\r, referer:
> http//localhost/cgi-bin/cgiHandleEvents.cgi
>
> [Wed Mar 16 15:01:37 2011] [error]
> [client 127.0.0.1]   what():  I/O
> error\r, referer:
> http//localhost/cgi-bin/cgiHandleEvents.cgi

The current code contains no message handler. In my opinion on POST the page should simply reload. For checking the code you can exchange the lines containing the different form method.

```
#include "cgicc/CgiDefs.h"
#include "cgicc/Cgicc.h"
#include "cgicc/HTTPHTMLHeader.h"
#include "cgicc/HTMLClasses.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace cgicc;

int main()
{
   Cgicc formData;
   Cgicc cgi;

   cout<< HTTPHTMLHeader() << endl;
   cout<< HTMLDoctype(HTMLDoctype::eStrict) << endl;
   cout<< html().set("lang", "EN").set("dir", "LTR") << endl;

   // Set up the HTML document
   cout<< html() << head() << title("Cgicc example") << head() << endl;
   cout<< body().set("bgcolor","#cccccc").set("text","#000000").set("link","#0000ff").set("vlink","#000080") << endl;

   try
   {
       cout<< h2("Test CGIcc form") << endl;
       cout<< "GNU cgicc v" << cgi.getVersion() << "<BR>" << endl;

       //cout<< "<form method=\"post\" action=\"cgiHandleEvents.cgi\">"<< endl;
       cout<< "<form method=\"get\" action=\"cgiHandleEvents.cgi\">"<< endl;

       cout<< "    Value 1:" << endl;
       cout<< "    <input type=\"text\" name=\"value1\">" << endl;
       cout<< "    <p></p>" << endl;
       cout<< "    Value 2:" << endl;
       cout<< "    <select name=\"value2\">" << endl;
       cout<< "        <option value=\"option1\">Option 1" << endl;
       cout<< "        <option value=\"option2\">Option 2" << endl;
       cout<< "        <option value=\"option3\">Option 3" << endl;
       cout<< "    </select>" << endl;
       cout<< "    <p></p>" << endl;
       cout<< "    Value 3:" << endl;
       cout<< "    <input type=\"radio\" name=\"value3\" value=\"button1\" checked=\"checked\">Button1" << endl;
       cout<< "    <input type=\"radio\" name=\"value3\" value=\"button2\">Button2" << endl;
       cout<< "    <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"value4\" value=\"data4\">" << endl;
       cout<< "    <p></p>" << endl;
       cout<< "    <input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\">" << endl;
       cout<< "</form>" << endl;
   }
   catch(exception& e)
   {
       // handle any errors here.
       cout<< h2("ERROR!!!") << endl;
   }
   // Close the HTML document
   cout << body() << html();
   return 0;   // To avoid Apache errors.
}
```

Does anybody have an idea what the problem is?

Comment: Do you have a copy of a HTTP POST request? Generally POST will have a body while GET will not.

Comment: What do you mean when you ask for the "HTTP POST" request? The requests are build identical by my application but using different parameters (<form method="post"> vs <form method="get">). As I wrote already you can exchange the two lines with the "form request" by removing the comment marks from the line with the POST, and add comment marks to the line with the GET. Maybe this is an issue of my apache configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the errors. First error is malformed HTML. Look out for opening and closing tag for html not enclosing the complete html page!

```
cout<< html().set("lang", "EN").set("dir", "LTR") << endl;
// Set up the HTML document
cout<< html() << head() << title("Cgicc example") << head() << endl;
```

Second error seems to be

```
Cgicc formData;
```

I do not know why this leads to an error. But If I do not use it the POST request works fine. If I think twice it makes no sense to have 2 instances of Cgicc. This is my fault. m(

But I think this is a bug inside cgicc. I will file a bug on savanna...

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a very late reply, but maybe it well help someone.

Yesterday I started working with C++ Cgi scripts for the very first time.  I discovered that declaring Cgicc multiple times in the code while submitting data with the POST method (GET works fine) caused this exact same problem for me as well.  It was resolved by declaring Cgicc globally, and thus, only once in the code.

Comment: Thank you for your response. After thinking about the topic you will come to conclusion that another CGI object makes absolutely no sense in a CGI-Executable. :-)  BTW: If you still have to deal with CGI written in C++ have a look at [NLTemplate](https://github.com/catnapgames/NLTemplate)! Now after some changes this HTML template engine is very fast and will help you to get clean code by dividing markup/design from C++ code.